# What is a method to read an excel cell with the currency format and coded with a formula using java?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, automation

I have a currency format cell which is numeric and its coded with a formula. I can read the formula, no problem. I tried with `cell.getNumericCellValue()`, but its reading it as 0.00. I've tried converting it to a string using `setCellType` and reading it with `cell.getStringCellType()`. I've also tried using `DataFromatter()` and applying `formatCellValue(cell)` and it reads the formula. I've also tried using `FormulaEvaluator`.

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
             cell.setCellFormula(formaCellValue.substring(1));
             evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

This is the error message I got for that:

> The specified formula '=ROUND(G65*E65,2)' starts with an equals sign which is not allowed.

Is there any method I haven't tried yet? Or can I convert the cell format to a general cell and try getting the value? If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = 
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
double value = evaluator.evaluate(cell).getNumberValue();
System.out.println(value);


cell.setCellType(CellType.TYPE_NUMERIC);
double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Instead of using the setCellFormula() method, you can try using the setCellValue() method and passing the result of the formula, not the formula itself.
You can also convert the cell format to a general cell, to do so you can use the setCellType(CellType.TYPE_NUMERIC) method and set the cell format to general format then you can use getNumericCellValue() method to get the value.